# Load a url with user input

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

This is my C# to fetch data from a JSON link.

```
string email = textBox1.Text;

string password = textBox2.Text;

string s = client.DownloadString("https://cunctatious-objecti.000webhostapp.com/Moderator_signup.php?name= +email & password= + password" );
```

The actual link is
`https://cunctatious-objecti.000webhostapp.com/Moderator_signup.php?name='faizan' & password='123'`.

The problem is that I want to take name and password from the user via TextBoxes and insert them in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your link formation doesn't seems correct because of string concatenation.

Try below changes :

```
client.DownloadString("https://cunctatious-objecti.000webhostapp.com/Moderator_signup.php?name="+email+"&password="+ password);
```